# Is it possible to call NotifyHost method in infopath forms buttons rule?

Tags: infopath2010

I need to call NotifyHost method in the button control which is in the infoptah form. Need to call this using a rule. Is this possible? If so please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by creating a data connection to submit the data to the host and calling the data connection in the button rule for submission of data to host

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be done using a rule? You could change the action of the button to "Rules and Custom Code" and access NotifyHost from there. You can also do whatever the button was previously doing (E.g. Submit, Rules, Validation, etc) in the code behind as well.

Comment: In infopath if we use, VSTA code for web enabled infopath form, if this form has to accessible for user from outside the domain, the dll has to be certified by a CA, other wise it invokes security warning in the client machine. Because of this we have decided to go for complete non code solution.